# Class constructor called upon sending different variables to a class member function

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, destructor

I'm studying for an OOP test in C++, and I'm trying to understand something about the idea of constructors.

In the code below:

Class A:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() { cout << "1"; }
    A(const A& a) { cout << "2"; }
    ~A(){ cout << "3"; }

    A anyFunc(A& a1, A* a2, A a3) {
        cout << "4";
        return *a2;
    }
};
```

Main:

```
#include"A.h"

void main() {   
    A a;
    a.anyFunc(a, &a, a);
}
```

This code prints `"1242333"`.

I understand the first `"1...."` because we create an object `a` of type `A` with the default constructor.

Later on, we send to the member function of class `A` the object we created first by reference, then as a pointer, and last by value.

I don't understand what the compiler does after that. Why would it go and use the copy constructor and print `"2"`, then print `"4"`, and then again go to the copy constructor to print `"2"`? Basically, creating `a2` and `a3`. I understand the last `"....333"` that are printed, since if we created the local static objects `a1`,`a2`,`a3` then the compiler calls the destructor when those variables "die" in the end.

Trying to understand how constructors work in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1` is printed when the variable `a` in `main()` is default-constructed (object #1).

`2` is printed when the `a3` parameter of `anyFunc()` is copy-constructed (object #2) from `a`. Since `a3` is passed in **by value**, it is a *copy* of whichever `A` object is given to it.  The `a1` and `a2` parameters do not create new objects, they simply refer to existing objects (in this case, to the same object - `a` in `main()`).

`4` is printed when `anyFunc()` begins running. No new `A` object is created here.

`2` is printed again when the return value of `anyFunc()` is copy-constructed (object #3) from `*a2`.  Since `anyFunc()` returns an `A` object **by value**, it returns a *temporary copy* of whichever `A` object is being `return`'ed.  The caller of `anyFunc()` decides what it wants to do with that returned copy - save it to a local variable, pass it to another function, or just ignore it (as your example is doing).

`3` is printed when the `a3` parameter of `anyFunc()` is destructed when `anyFunc()` exits.

`3` is printed when the temporary `A` object returned by `anyFunc()` is destructed.

`3` is printed when the `a` variable in `main()` is destructed when `main()` exits.

Comment: Thank you! your detailed answer really made sense to me and made me realize the idea of passing a3 as value - making it create a local copy of the object we got.

What still makes no sense to me is after we print the "4", why would we print "2" when we return *a2? The object a2 is the address of a from the main - and when we return the VALUE of the address we hold in a2, or am I mistaken? because I don't see how we would create a new instance and use the copy constructor again.

Comment: @Zig302 "*why would we print "2" when we return *a2?*" - I addressed that in my answer, was something unclear about it? `anyFunc()`'s return value is returned **by value**, so it is **another copy**, hence why the copy constructor gets called. Every time a variable is passed around **by value**, it is copied. `a2` is just a pointer to the `a` variable in `main()`, yes, but that pointer is being dereferenced to access the underlying `A` object in memory, and then the `return` statement **copies** that object into a new *temporary* `A` object that is passed back to the caller.

Comment: Thank you! To summarize, correct me if I'm wrong: 
Every time we pass by value OR return by value, we create a local object in that scope. If my function anyFunc would be declared as "A& anyFunc", we would return the argument by reference and we wouldn't create a new local object. What was not intuitive for me was that (in the original anyFunc I posted) even if I returned a3 or a1, which already have local objects that exist in that scope - I would still be called to the copy constructor. But if I understood you, as long as my func returns by value, it will create a new local scope object.

Comment: @Zig302 "*local object in scope*" is not the right terminology. But yes, your understanding is essentially correct. Any time a variable is passed around **by value**, whether that is to a parameter, a return value, another variable, etc, a copy of its *current value* is made. That is what **by value** means, vs passing it around **by reference** or **by pointer** instead.

Comment: Much appreciated, really! Now just for my own sake, what would be the right terminology for what is happening?

Answer (score 3):

For starters according to the C++ Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main()
```

As for your question then in this statement

```
A a;
```

there is called the default constructor

```
"1     "
```

then in this call

```
a.anyFunc(a, &a, a);
```

for the third argument to create the object that corresponds to the third parameter `a3` there is used the copy constructor

```
"12    ".
```

The function gets the control

```
"124   ".
```

The function returns an object of the type `A` using the expression `*a`

```
A anyFunc(A& a1, A* a2, A a3) {
    cout << "4";
    return *a2;
}
```

So again the copy constructor is called to create the returned object

```
"1242   ".
```

Then the destructor is called for the object that corresponds to the parameter `a3`

```
"12423  ".
```

Then destroyed the temporary returned object

```
"124233 ".
```

And at last there is destroyed the object defined in main in this declaration

```
A a;
```

As a result you have

```
"1242333".
```

That is there were created three objects. The first one - in main. The second one that corresponds to the parameter `a3`. And at last the returned temporary object. For each of these objects there was called the destructor.

Pay attention to that if you would call the function like

```
a.anyFunc( a, &a, A() );
```

then the ouput would be

```
1142333
```

That is instead of the second digit `2` there will be the digit `1` due to the copy elision.

Comment: The thing that I've missed in understanding is that if my func returns an object by value, it also means that it creates a local object in the same scope, no matter what it returns. I assumed that happens only when I pass by value, but haven't thought it happens the other way around. It's a little counter intuitive for me, because even if I returned a3 or a1, which already have local objects that exist in that scope - I would still be called to the copy constructor.

Comment: @Zig302 you don't seem to be accounting for the fact that the scope of the return value is the caller of the function, not the function itself. The lifetime of the returned object is created and destroyed in the caller's scope, not the function's scope. The lifetime of any local variable inside of the function does not affect the lifetime of the return value (but you do have to be careful when the return value is a reference/pointer to a variable that is local inside of the function, because that will cause major problems for the caller).